# heroForm.errors?.xxx in angular forms template

Tags: javascript, angular2-forms

Why do we have a question mark in a property? What is **'?'** marks significance.

```
<div *ngIf="heroForm.errors?.identityRevealed && (heroForm.touched || heroForm.dirty)" class="cross-validation-error-message alert alert-danger">
Name cannot match alter ego.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not a Typescript operator this is safe navigation operator or elvis operator.

Angular 2 has a safe navigation operator in templates.

? "Question Mark" is not a ternary operator in typescript, ? is used for safe loading the HTML doc while a component is generating the DOC for browser display.

**Safe Navigation Operator (Elvis Operator):**

The Safe Navigation Operator is also known as the "Elvis Operator". This operator is very useful to protect against null and undefined values in property paths. This operator allows us to navigate an object path in situations when we are not aware whether a path exists or not. It returns value of the object path if it exists, else it returns the null value. It is very useful to prevent null-reference exceptions.

**Syntax:**

```
object?.path
```

Refer:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-safe-navigation-operator-in-angular-2/